# Por que COBOL ainda é a linguagem preferida no mundo dos negócios?

Tags: cobol

Como todos sabem COBOL é muito usado por instituições financeiras, onde apenas a interface é feita utilizando linguagens atuais como Java.

- O custo para manter *mainframes* é grande, mas a migração para uma linguagem atual é maior?
- Atualmente é muito usado mas daqui a 20 anos, ainda vai continuar vantajoso continuar utilizando *mainframes* e dando manutenção em sistemas legados **COBOL**?
- Existe alguma limitação que faça essa migração do **COBOL** não ser feita? (Ex: Consistência de dados)
- Na época que **COBOL** começou a ser popular na área de negócios, não existia outra linguagem semelhante ou ela é única que continua viva?

Comment: Não tenho absolutamente nada de útil a contribuir, mas sempre que vejo algo relacionado ao COBOL me vêm à mente uma frase de Osvaldo Santo André: "Quem diz que o Cobol morreu, cuidado! Pois sofre o grande risco de ter seu atestado de óbito e a Nota Fiscal de seu caixão feitos por um sistema Cobol"

Comment: Acredito eu é pq é custoso atualizar todo o sistema legado, não só em dinheiro, mas em esforços, recursos, tempo e etc.

Comment: Tem mais um ditado que garante a sobrevivência de sistemas feitos em COBOL: não tente consertar o que não está quebrado.

Comment: Esta pergunta não cumpre os padrões deste site e deve ser encerrada.

Comment: Discussão interessante, mas que não pertinente a filosofia do site. E olha que trabalhei anos com COBOL.

Comment: Não vejo motivo porque fechar, deixei aberta porque a pergunta é direta, bem-estruturada e **não** tem nada a ver com opinião, e sim com respostas únicas e objetivas (A única exceção poderia ser a segunda dúvida).

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo Editei.

Comment: Primeiro para responder a pergunta deveria ser respondido se o fato é verdade, COBOL ainda domina o mercado corporativo ? Qual a métrica ?

Comment: http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2014/01/22/language-rankings-1-14/  http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html http://www.computerworld.com/slideshow/detail/98085#slide9

Comment: Onde COBOL é utilizado em Mainframes, COBOL domina em Mainframes. Onde COBOL não é usado em Mainframes, obviamente que não domina. Não há inquéritos que não são capazes de refletir essa realidade é qualquer uso para medir alguma coisa a ver com COBOL. "Eu vou fazer um levantamento de todos os elementos do planeta Terra, por amostragem a atmosfera" Não se surpreenda se algo, o que não entrar na atmosfera está perdida.

Comment: Negativei as respostas baseadas em "achismo", como disse @BillWoodger: `Pessoas que não sabem sobre COBOL, falando sobre COBOL; pessoas que não sabem sobre Mainframes, falando sobre Mainframes.` . . . . Memória histórica: meu primeiro estágio foi com COBOL, foi quando resolvi abandonar Ciencia da Computação e fazer Comunicação Social o.O

Comment: [COBOL IS EVERYWHERE, EVERY DAYi](http://pt.slideshare.net/Micro-Focus/114593-mf-cobol-everydayinfographicfinalhr?from_search=1)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Mais alguém consegue ver o problema com essa pergunta? Pessoas que não sabem sobre COBOL, falando de COBOL, pessoas que não sabem sobre Mainframes, falando de Mainframes.

Vamos dividir o "negócio" de forma mais apropriada.

Quanto menor a empresa, menos relevante o idioma, sistema operacional e hardware se tornam.

À medida que progredimos para empresas cada vez maiores, as escolhas se tornam mais importantes.

Nas maiores empresas, com uma quantidade enorme de coisas para fazer, transações financeiras, registrando volume enorme e variado de ações, esse tipo de coisa, com precisão e rapidez: lá você encontrará os sistemas existentes em Mainframes, da IBM, com o programas dentro desses sistemas rodando principalmente em COBOL. Com maior ou menor nível de "interoperabilidade" com outras "coisas" (outros sistemas não-mainframe, serviços web, bancos de dados externos, quaisquer que sejam).

Por que COBOL é tão rápido? Por que a atenção a isso?

Devido ao tipo de linguagem que COBOL é. Campos de comprimento fixo. Decimais aritméticos. Desenvolvido muitos anos antes da existência da teoria moderna sobre linguagens de programação, há pouco para proteger o programador. Um alfanumérico pode ser tratado como um número, e não no sentido que uma linguagem interpretada pode fazer, mas por ponderação por parte do programador.

Obviamente uma descrição mais completa do idioma, mesmo sem comparações, iria preencher pelo menos um livro.

Adicione a isso, o Mainframe IBM, com registros fixos ou de comprimento conhecido (sem delimitadores de registro) e instruções de máquina decimais disponíveis.

Mais uma vez, pelo menos, mais um livro.

Acrescente a isso a experiência acumulada de muitos anos de sistemas massivos.

Acrescente a isso... Eu poderia continuar...

```
01  BRANCH-TOTAL COMP-3 PIC S9(9)V99.
01  ACCOUNT-TOTAL COMP-3 PIC S9(9)V99.

...

ADD ACCOUNT-TOTAL TO BRANCH-TOTAL
```

Esse ADD pode (dependendo das opções de compilação) gerar uma instrução de máquina. Uma instrução de máquina. Entendeu? Uma. Sem problema de arredondamento algum. Precisão decimal de 100%. Em uma CPU com uma velocidade de clock que qualquer um poderia desejar.

Substituir um sistema que está cheio disso, em uma combinação de hardware/OS que pode funcionar por anos sem a necessidade de um re-start (IPL), sem constantes melhorias de segurança, e que será executado inalterado (mesmo sem uma re-compilação), em 20-50 anos de tempo, não é uma tarefa trivial.

E se alguém encarar essa tarefa, é melhor fazer ela direito.

Lembre-se, você não pode depender só do hardware ficar mais rápido, porque ao mesmo tempo o negócio demanda mais, então o excesso de capacidade/poder nunca existe de verdade (ou pelo menos não por muito tempo).

---

COBOL foi desenvolvido em uma parceria entre sete grandes fabricantes de computadores e o governo dos EUA (incluindo os militares) para fornecer uma linguagem padrão em diferentes tipos de hardware, especificamente para a programação de negócios.

Não haviam outras linguagens naquela época que funcionavam desta forma  para fins comerciais. (cada fabricante tinha sistemas de programação específicos para os suas linhas de máquinas, muitas vezes diferentes, mesmo entre suas próprias máquinas)

Os custos de propriedade e operação de Mainframes hoje referem-se à quantidade de poder de processamento envolvido. A capacidade de processamento é necessária para a enorme quantidade de processamento transacional efetuada.

IBM tem planos de desenvolvimento para COBOL para os próximos 50 anos (ver https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLMqkuou2-s). Isto, obviamente, significa que eles têm planos de desenvolvimento para computadores mainframe para o mesmo período.

Migrando do Mainframe para outro hardware para o processamento de "back end" não tem limites, mas o sistema de substituição tem de ser: tão  preciso quanto; tão confiável quanto; não custe mais para ser mantido; estável por longos períodos de tempo ("compatibilidade retroativa") - A arquitetura IBM System/360, que recentemente comemorou seu aniversário de 50 anos, ainda é a base para a atual z/Architechture para mainframes IBM. Os programas aplicativos escritos há 50 anos, ainda tem uma chance excepcionalmente boa chance de funcionar hoje. É rotina para sistemas escritos na década de 1970 ainda estarem em execução hoje.

Uma abordagem comum tem sido a implementação de novos sistemas em um novo hardware com novas linguagens, e executar os sistemas de Mainframe existentes ao lado, à procura de oportunidades para reduzir a carga de trabalho dos Mainframe a medida que ela cresça. Para estes, o Teste Do Tempo ainda não foi concluído.

RPG e suas variantes é uma outra linguagem "longa vida" da IBM, mas que sempre foi destinado a sistemas menores (Mini-computadores).

Mainframes (e os sistemas que correm) ainda são importantes? Olhe para os relatórios financeiros da IBM. Somas importantes ainda estão sendo gastas em novo hardware e novo hardware ainda está sendo constantemente desenvolvidos, a um custo considerável. A partir disso, tire as conclusões você mesmo.

Para mais informações sobre Mainframes, a IBM tornou todos os manuais disponíveis ao público, e tem publicado um grande número de Redbooks sobre vários assuntos de Mainframe. Para os interessados ​​em mais pesquisa, mas sem conhecimento de Mainframes, este é um bom ponto de partida: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246366.html

Desculpas pelo Google Translate

---

Can anyone see the problem with the question? People who don't know about COBOL, talking about COBOL, people who don't know about Mainframes, talking about Mainframes.

Let's split the "business" up into something more appropriate.

The smaller a business, the less relevant the language, operating system and hardware become.

As we progress through larger and larger businesses, the choices become more important.

At the very largest of businesses, with massive amounts of stuff to do, financial transactions, recording enormous volume and variety of stock, that type of thing, accurately and rapidly: there you'll find existing systems on Mainframes, from IBM, with the programs within those systems being mainly COBOL. With a greater or lesser amount of "interoperability" between other "things" (other non-Mainframe systems, web services, external databases, whatever).

Why is COBOL so fast? Why the attention to that?

Because of the type of language COBOL is. Fixed-length fields. Decimal arithmatic. Developed many years before the existence of modern theory on programming languages, there is little to protect the programmer. An alphanumeric can be treated as a number, not in the sense that an interpreted language might do, but by deliberation on the part of the programmer.

Because there is lots of stuff to do, and to do it within time to meet the business needs, it has to be done fast.

Obviously a fuller description of the language, let alone comparisons, would fill at least a book.

Add to that, the IBM Mainframe, with fixed- or known-length records (no record delimeters) and decimal machine instructions available.

Again, at least another book.

Add to that the cumulative experience of many years of massive systems.

Add to that... I could go on...

```
01  BRANCH-TOTAL COMP-3 PIC S9(9)V99.
01  ACCOUNT-TOTAL COMP-3 PIC S9(9)V99.

...

ADD ACCOUNT-TOTAL TO BRANCH-TOTAL
```

That ADD can (depending on compile options) generate one machine instruction. One machine instruction. Go it? One. No rounding problems at all. 100% decimal accuracy. On a CPU with a clock speed anyone would wish for.

To replace a system which is full of that, on a hardware/OS combination which can run for years without requiring a re-start (IPL), without constant "security" upgrades, and which will run unchanged (without even a re-compile) in 20-50 years time, is a non-trivial task.

If that task is taken on, you'd better get it right.

Remember, you can't just rely on hardware getting faster, because at the same time the business wants more, so the excess capacity/power never really exists (or not for long).

---

Original, recovered from a "recently closed tab" (thanks FireFox) and including some minor edits. Please feel free to edit google's attempt at your language:

COBOL was developed in partnership between the seven large computer manufacturers and the US Government (including the military) to provide a standard language across different hardware specifically for business programming.

There were no other languages at the time which would operated in this way (each manufacturer had specific programming systems for their own ranges of machines, often different even between their own ranges) for business purposes.

Costs of owning and operating Mainframes today relate to the amount of processing power involved. Processing power is required for the massive amount of transactional processing carried out.

IBM has development plans for COBOL for the next 50 years (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLMqkuou2-s). This obviously means they have development plans for Mainframe computers for the same period.

Migrating from Mainframe to other hardware for the "back end" processing has no limits, but the replacement system has to be: as accurate: as reliable; not more expensive to run; stable for the coming many years ("backwards compatable") - IBM's System/360 Architechture, which recently celebrated its 50th birthday, is the basis for today's z/Architechture for IBM Mainframes. Application programs written 50 years ago, still stand an exceptionally good chance of working today. It is routine for systems written in the 1970s to still be able to run today.

A common approach has been to implement new systems on new hardware with new languages, and run the existing Mainframe systems alongside, looking for opportunities to reduce the Mainframe workload as they arise. For these, The Test of Time has not been completed yet.

RPG, and its variants, is another long-lived IBM language, but that was always aimed at smaller (Mini-computer) systems.

Are Mainframes (and the systems they run) still important? Look at IBM's financial reports. Considerable amounts of money are still being spent on new hardware, and new hardware is still being constantly developed, at considerable cost. Draw what conclusions you like from that.

For more information on Mainframes, IBM has made all their manuals publicly available, and have published a large number of Redbooks on various Mainframe subjects. For those interested in more research, but with no Mainframe background, this one is a good starting-point: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246366.html

Comment: pelo menos posta o Fonte de onde retirou o texto

Comment: Desculpe, fonte é a minha cabeça. Você quer uma referência para alguma parte?

Comment: I liked your answer, you have the original? In portuguese has errors of agreement

Comment: @BrunoRozendo updated with original text. A bit lucky on that...

Comment: COBOL will outlive most of us `ou` o COBOL vai enterrar a maioria de nós :D

Comment: Uma leitura tão curta e uma ótima visão de Cobol e Mainframe quanto as suas diferenças com relação a outras plataformas. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Uma instituição bancária precisa processar uma quantidade imensa de dados diariamente, não pode se dar ao luxo do sistema ficar "fora do ar" de vez em quando, e necessita de uma resposta correta para cálculos complexos em um tempo predeterminado. Por essa razão, migrar sistemas - principalmente de uma plataforma para outra completamente diferente - não é algo que se possa fazer rotineiramente, dado seu alto custo e principalmente risco.

Não sei como são as versões modernas de COBOL, mas pelo que sei há uma vantagem explícita em utilizá-lo no sentido de que ela é capaz de manipular o banco de dados diretamente (pelo menos os bancos que foram projetados para fazer interface com essa linguagem). Embora o processamento de SQL seja relativamente leve nos usos mais corriqueiros, ainda é um *overhead* que faz diferença se for eliminado. Nem todo uso de COBOL evita SQL, é claro, e não saberia dizer que porcentagem dos sistemas atuais - se é que alguma - ainda usa essa técnica, mas ainda é fato conhecido (acreditado?) que essa plataforma oferece um desempenho além do usual em sistemas transacionais.

Quanto a se manter mainframes, é bom lembrar que a crescente virtualização de servidores permitiu que se trouxesse essa plataforma para a era do *cloud computing*: não apenas há constante manutenção a esse ambiente como também ele se modernizou para tanto dar suporte a aplicações legadas, permitir aplicações novas em linguagens modernas (não todas, mas algumas) e inclusive aprimorar os compiladores COBOL para tornar esses sistemas ainda mais eficientes.

Hoje em dia um profissional que domina COBOL é difícil de ser encontrado, mas por outro lado ele é muito bem pago, de modo que sempre existirá uma porcentagem de desenvolvedores que seguirá por esse rumo. O mesmo vale para Fortran - linguagem ainda muito utilizada no meio científico.

Por fim, quanto ao último item, não sei te dizer ao certo, mas uma rápida olhada na ["linha do tempo de linguagens de programação"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages) (Wikipedia, em inglês) noto que a cada década (inclusive a nossa) surgem diversas linguagens novas, umas ficam populares e outras vão sendo esquecidas. Com certeza as linguagens da época eram mais semelhantes entre si do que entre elas e as linguagens de hoje, porém suficientemente distintas quanto, digamos, Java e Python. Ou seja, acredito que seja sim o caso de COBOL ser "a única que continua viva".

Comment: Disclaimer: embora eu tenha trabalhado *com pessoas* que já utilizaram COBOL e Fotran extensivamente, eu próprio nunca o fiz, de modo que não falo por experiência própria, mas sim o que me recordo do relato de terceiros.

Answer (score 4):

Não tem nada haver com ser preferido ou não. O que acontece muito é que, imagine sua empresa que tem um baita sistemão que faz um monte de coisa e que te satisfaz e não dá problema nenhum. Nunca deu inconsistencia de dados, é rápido para resgatar e/ou visualizar as informações que você precisa.

Um empresário se pergunta: Pra que zorra vou trocar este sistema? É mais barato comprar/desenvolver um novo e com novas tecnologias ou pagar um funcionário/terceirizado que possa fazer alguma implementaçõezinhas "quando" necessário?

Por mais que eu seja um programador, acho que esta é a visão dos empresários.

Comment: Ser um programador não faz diferença. É um caso de negócio, o que deve ser influenciada com cuidado pelo departamento de TI, e não com emoção ou preferência. Entendi errado, e os custos podem ser enormes. Por outro lado, super computadores experientes tendem a se aposentar ou morrer nos próximos anos :-) Isso é um factor a ter em conta.

Comment: ^_^... Então, como eu disse "Por mais que eu seja um programador, acho que esta é a visão dos empresários.", quis me fazer entender o motivo de existir ainda muitos sistemas em COBOL. Porquê quem paga é o empresário e não o programador, analista, gerente de TI, etc... Então o responsável pela TI é quem deve analisar, documentar e apresentar ao empresário os contras e prós de ainda utilizarem-no. Mas só dependerá desta visão/motivação que o empresário terá e aceitará a mudança.

Comment: COmplementando... Tenho esta idéia de ainda existir muitos sistemas em COBOL por falta de conhecimento técnico do empresário, eles só entendem "números", na maioria.

Comment: Meu Português não é suficiente para a nuance. Poderíamos estar concordando. Não devemos levar o negócio em algo mudo que entra em colapso depois de cinco anos de desenvolvimento e implementação. Nem devemos deixar tal negócio dedicarem um caminho sem reclamar. Isto não é para dizer que há uma solução pronta de um tamanho para todos. Não altere. Fazer a mudança. Nem faz sentido fora do contexto específico. É por isso que eu sinalizado a questão de opinião. Rejeitado.

Answer (score 3):

**O custo para manter mainframes é grande, mas a migração para uma linguagem atual é maior?**

O custo para manter mainframes é grande, contudo, os mainframe são conhecidos pela disponibilidade "nine nines" 99,9999999%. Como cliente de um banco, eu gosto de ter o meu dinheiro sempre acessível!

O custo para uma migração para uma linguagem actual depende de empresa para empresa e do retorno sobre o investimento dessa migração. Adicionalmente, o risco de se migrar um sistema pode não compensar essa migração.

**Atualmente é muito usado mas daqui a 20 anos, ainda vai continuar vantajoso continuar utilizando mainframes e dando manutenção em sistemas legados COBOL?**

Claro que sim! Há sistemas que têm código a funcionar desde 1980 e ainda hoje estão em funcionamento!

**Existe alguma limitação que faça essa migração do COBOL não ser feita? (Ex: Consistência de dados)**

Em termos técnicos não. Contudo, o COBOL em mainframe usa um encoding que a maior parte das pessoas não conhece, que é o EBCDIC. Como é um sistema que só os dinossauros conhecem (sim, porque os dinossauros ainda existem!), são necessários muitos dinossauros para migrar um sistema cobol!

**Na época que COBOL começou a ser popular na área de negócios, não existia outra linguagem semelhante ou ela é única que continua viva?**

Penso que o Fortran é da mesma altura do COBOL, no entanto, só os dinossauros é que sabem COBOL!

Comment: IBM has announced, this month, Version 6 of Enterprise COBOL. This follows on from V5.2 a year ago, and V5 in 2013. New Mainframes over the last year are the z13, LinuxOne, and the z13s (announced this month). No, it is not just dinosaurs.

Comment: I agree with you... I know COBOL and I'm not a dinasaur (at least I think I'm not)! I'm anxious to see whats new with the integration between COBOL and Java with V6.

Answer (score 2):

COBOL, hoje, é uma das linguagens mais seguras e rápidas do meio comercial. Não estou dizendo que C ou JAVA sejam "frágeis", mas o COBOL, por não ter tanta documentação e material disponível para consulta (não da mesma forma que outras linguagens), se tornou uma ferramenta muito interessante para quem visa a segurança. Ao contrario de que muitos pensam, o COBOL não esta "desatualizado" ou "morto". Assim como o C, ele sofre constantes mudanças. Ainda existe uma evolução nele, mesmo que sua sintaxe seja antiga. Deixando assim, seu desenvolvimento, de certa forma, lento. Ele não parou no tempo. E com certeza migrar um sistema todo, principalmente bancário, para uma outra linguagem, ainda quando a atual está cumprindo seu papel, é perda de dinheiro e um retrabalho enorme sem grandes retornos.

> Na época que COBOL começou a ser popular na área de negócios, não existia outra linguagem semelhante, ou ela é única que continua "viva"?

Ele foi criado para esse propósito, ser uma linguagem de bancos, comércio, etc.

Comment: A longo prazo não seria interessante a migração?

Comment: Não vejo necessidade, já que como ele não esta estagnado e vem provando cada dia que passa ser seguro. Se não surgir uma linguagem mais eficiente eu acredito que irão manter o COBOL ou utilizar uma variação dele para novos desafios

Comment: -1 porque segurança por ofuscação (neste caso, por falta de documentação e de material) não é segurança de verdade. Uma pessoa com vontade de atacar um sistema feito em COBOL não teria mais dificuldades do que no caso de sistemas feitos em outras tecnologias. Na verdade, devido justamente a falta de documentação, fica até mais fácil, pois torna-se também mais custoso para os próprios desenvolvedores COBOL fazerem algo seguro de verdade.

Comment: @Renan Concordo, citei a falta de documentação como um fator que pode modificar o nível de segurança pois a grande maioria de "hackers" são hackers de tutoriais e que não tem a capacidade de descobrir algo sozinho. Seu comentário se torna válido para o 1% que são hackers de verdade.

Comment: @brhvitor6 Mas esses hackers de tutorias não existem, são apenas Script Kiddies.

Comment: @NULL haha também, mas como frequentei muito tempo forums de desenvolvimento de cheats para jogos vi que existem muitos "desenvolvedores" que aproveitam classes/arquivos dupados (dump) de outros desenvolvedores mais "skilleds" e desenvolvem os seus próprios programas, em sua maioria tem um conhecimento até razoável em C/JAVA/LUA, mas não tem um nohall em engenharia reversa por ex.

Comment: @Renan, Se você não sabe segurança Mainframe, então por favor não falar sobre isso. Se você não sabe segurança Mainframe, você sabe que é um disparate. Todos os manuais da IBM geralmente disponíveis, estão disponíveis on-line, da IBM. Isto inclui blocos de controle, segurança, idiomas, serviços públicos, bancos de dados, comunicações, tudo. Tudo o que você pode pensar, e muito, muito mais. Ao longo de muitos lançamentos.

Comment: Não custa lembrar o BOL é de linguagem orientada (a) negócios ...

Comment: Então a linguagem é segura por ter pouca documentação? Tomara que não seja esse o motivo!

Comment: "mas o COBOL, por não ter tanta documentação e material disponível para consulta (não da mesma forma que outras linguagens), se tornou uma ferramenta muito interessante para quem visa a segurança." Desculpa mas você falou uma besteira muito grande. A IBM disponibiliza um vasto material sobre a linguagem e todo o ambiente de mainframe. Aqui no stackoverflow as pessoas só falam do que sabem e têm certeza. Essa foi uma afirmação muito leviana de alguém que não trabalha com COBOL.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas estatísticas recentes para reforçar o uso do COBOL e do ambiente Mainframe nas empresas:

92 dos 100 maiores bancos do mundo usam cobol/mainframe;
23 dos 25  maiores revendedores do mundo usam cobol/mainframe;
Todas as 10 empresas mais seguras do mundo usam cobol/mainframe;
cobol/mainframe suportam 90% de todas as transações de cartão de crédito
cobol/mainframe executam 30 bilhões de transações por dia

Antes de pensarmos qual a tecnologia ideal, temos que pensar como consultores, como empresários. Avaliação custo/benefício além da segurança de informação ditam a regra sobre implementação de sistemas em empresas.

Outro ponto relevante é que não importa a linguagem se a solução não for bem sucedida, bem aplicada.

Answer (score -1):

Bem vamos lá:
Inicialmente COBOL não é a linguagem preferida no mundo dos negócios, por ser uma linguagem antiga, é largamente utilizada em Bancos e Instituições Financeiras.
Além desses segmentos, as Estatais de Infra-estrutura também utilizando muito linguagens de Mainframe.
A saber:
Devido ao grande volume de processamento de dados, o Cobol e outras linguagens mainframe como Natural, Adabas (os dois da SoftwareAG), Cobol, Easytrieve dentre outras se tornaram linguagens extremamente populares.
Hoje acredita-se que mais de 70% dos códigos existentes no mundo ainda sejam em alguma linguagem Mainframe.
Além disso, a "dificuldade" em se invadir um ambiente Mainframe também sempre foi muito grande, dando um "q" de segurança aos dados bancários.
Outro fator que faz com que o Cobol e outras linguagens ainda sejam amplamente utilizado é o fato acima citado de que ainda existe muito código nessa linguagem e a reescrita desses códigos seria extremamente caro, e se está funcionando bem, não tem motivo para investir em reescrita.
Hoje, através de diversas ferramentas, pode-se fazer integração de diversas linguagens com o Mainframe, tornando essa linguagem ainda mais "imortal".

Comment: Olá @Andre. Tente estruturar melhor a sua resposta, está bem confusa para leitura.