# Por que Python é tão atual?

Tags: python

Observei que os principais sites do mundo (Google, Facebook, YouTube) ainda usam Python. Encontrei em diversos sites as vantagens de usar Python (simplicidade, robustez...), porém ainda sigo com as dúvidas:

1. Por que Python é tão atual?
2. Java por ser mais atual não faria tudo o que Python faz?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor sua dúvida? O que seria exatamente _"atual"_? Você quer uma comparação entre as linguagens?

Comment: O que é ser "tão atual" e "mais atual que o tão atual" pra você?

Comment: Atual seria no sentido ser popular e amplamente usada, pelo o que eu percebo, inclusive pelas perguntas aqui do site, mesmo fazendo algumas décadas de sua criação .

Comment: @AndréFilipe pelo tempo de criação, li python foi criada em 1989, e java em 1995, me corrija se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Eu não conheço muito python mas vi bastante ela ser recomendada em várias vezes como a linguagem para aprender a programar, devido sintaxe simples e intuitiva, outro ponto a favor é sua versatilidade, é muito usada em IA (inteligência artificial), data science (ciência dos dados), criação de servidores web e aplicações desktop, tudo isso aliado a uma boa performance

Comment: Se atualidade fosse atributo de superioridade em uma linguagem hoje todos estaríamos programando em Haskell.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Haskell é mais velha que Python :)

Comment: @Maniero, você está correto, elas tem um ano de diferença.

Comment: python é muito facil de entender logo é  muito produtivo

Java é muito prolixo comparado com python e é essencialmente Orientado a Objetos

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Observei que os principais sites do mundo (Google, Facebook, YouTube)

Premissa falsa. Podem usar pontualmente para algum *script* ou algum código que o time responsável achou que deveria usar, mas eles não são fundamentalmente escritos em Python.

Entenda que todos os locais que se propõem a falar bem de uma ferramenta acabam fazendo isso mesmo, ainda que tente dizer que é imparcial. Claro, muitos desses podem ter falado das desvantagens também de forma correta, podem não ter exagerado nas vantagens. Note que sua pergunta tem uma certa tendenciosidade para o Python, portanto eles conseguiram o que queriam, vender a ideia que Python é sensacional.

Já pensou que Python é o mesmo há anos, e até mesmo na grande mudança do 3.0 não mudou tanto assim? O que mudou foi a percepção das pessoas. Eu incentivei o uso de Python há mais de 10 anos, tinha até perdido as esperanças que ela fosse bem usada.

Sempre que alguém estiver falando só bem de uma linguagem é porque ela adora a linguagem, não porque a linguagem é tudo isso. E Python é cheio de problemas (ao contrário do marketing ela é cheia de WTF, só não tanto quanto PHP ou JS, mas tem um lado pior, as pessoas não falam sobre eles), tenho notado isso cada vez mais conforme vou olhando mais a fundo. O que não quer dizer que tenha mais que outras linguagens e que isso impeça sua boa utilização.

> Por que Python é tão atual?

Python é só mais uma linguagem de programação que resolve bem problemas que exijam expressar algoritmos computacionais. Ela foi criada há quase 30 anos atrás, evoluiu, como muitas linguagens, e foi adquirindo usuários ao longo do tempo. Ultimamente teve mais gente entrando na área e gostando. Por ter mais gente gostando tende a ter mais gente conhecendo e gostando, por isso todo mundo briga tanto para fazer sua tecnologia ser bem divulgada. Além disso não consigo explicar a popularidade repentina, exceto pelo que digo mais abaixo.

> Java por ser mais atual não faria tudo o que Python faz?

Não sei se isso faz sentido, Java foi criada 2 ou 3 anos depois. Pra falar a verdade nem sei bem o que é esse "atual", não sei se isso se encaixa em critérios objetivos. E subjetivos tanto faz. Se quer dizer ser popular, não é tão assim.

Java ainda é bem mais usada que Python, C# também, nem se fala em JavaScript, e até PHP ainda é mais usada. Mas o momento é de crescimento, então a percepção das pessoas é que ela está no topo. Quando algo era pouco usado e passa ter grande uso tende-se a distorcer a percepção que aquela demanda nova é muito grande ofuscando a demanda normal por tecnologias que estão em ritmo normal, mas ainda com total força.

Java faz tudo que Python faz e vice versa, assim como qualquer outra linguagem. Algumas permitem fazer certas coisas melhor, de forma mais fácil que outras, cada um com suas vantagens. Java por exemplo é muito mais robusta que Python, embora Python também seja, até certo ponto, então as vantagens que viu são relativas.

Por alguma razão Python começou ser usada com inteligência artificial, mas tudo o que pode fazer em Python nessa área pode fazer em outras linguagens, geralmente com mais performance e robustez. Sei lá, talvez porque seja mais fácil, quem não sabe programar acaba usando Python, afinal ela é mais permissiva, deixa você errar mais. Python facilita a ideia do "funciona então está certo" que as pessoas adoram, e que não é nem um pouco robusto. E quase todo mundo que entra na área hoje em dia não sabe programar e não pretende aprender, só querer produzir códigos.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Python é ligeiramente mais fácil de aprender que uma linguagem mais robusta. JavaScript é ainda mais, é mais rápida e mais permissiva (se usar TypeScript pode obter um pouco mais robustez) e de forma geral pode acessar todas bibliotecas de IA que Python acessa, então só posso acreditar que essa popularidade é apenas efeito manada, as pessoas vão para o Python porque tem gente falando que vai pra o Python (JS tem bem mais WTF).

Python é legal, tem vantagens e desvantagens. Serve melhor para algumas coisas, em outras não, mas pode ser usada praticamente pra tudo. Claro, a não ser que tenha alguma restrição de plataforma, você não pode rodar fácil em um *browser*, pode não rodar em algum dispositivo embarcado, ou pode não ser o ideal rodar no mobile, ou ainda dentro de um banco de dados, ou rodar direto no hardware, etc. Programadores profissionais usam a melhor ferramenta para a tarefa e Python é boa em várias delas, principais quando precisa de *scripts*. Muitos problemas precisam apenas deles.

## Popularidade

Aos poucos deu para entender que o que se fala aqui é popularidade, e meio que o tópico focou nisso.

É inegável que nos últimos anos Python cresceu muito, principalmente no último ano. O que mudou? Nada técnico, só que houve uma conjunção de fatores sociopolíticos que criaram uma espiral positiva que foi se retroalimentando. O que me faz ter cada vez mais certeza que a maioria das pessoas que trabalham na área não são engenheiros de verdade e estão sempre muito suscetíveis ao marketing, não à toa que as empresas e comunidades que estão por trás de certas tecnologias investem tanto esforço em fazer parecer que são populares. Popularidade atrai popularidade (isso me lembra [Namorada de Aluguel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092718/)). A linguagem sempre esteve aí do mesmo jeito de sempre. C# mudou muito mais, abriu o leque e não teve a mesma explosão, ainda teve nova adoção (por alguma razão as pessoas programam em C# como faziam há 10, 15 anos atrás, por isso tenho uma palestra mostrando como se programa do jeito moderno).

Infelizmente muitas pessoas não programam mais em PHP, elas programam em Laravel, CI, etc. Elas praticamente nunca programaram em Ruby, apenas em Rails. Assim como programavam mais em jQuery e agora em Angular, React ou Vue. Sim, nada disso são linguagens de programação, mas as pessoas nem tem essa noção. Quem tem entrado na área não tem aprendido programar, apenas usam essas tecnologias para juntar peças de Lego e fazer algo funcionar. Um dos trunfos de Python é que ela passou ter vários *frameworks* com funções distintas e não apenas vários web. O uso de Django é até pequeno na proporção da comunidade como um todo.

#### Tendenciosidade

Se olhar as vagas existentes significa apenas que a área tem muita rotatividade ou dificuldade de preencher vagas com profissionais adequados (está cada vez pior, cheio de vagas, cheio de gente entrando e as vagas não conseguem ser preenchidas porque as pessoas são muito baixamente qualificadas, e elas não querem fazer o dever de casa). Isso é pior em linguagens que atraem mais gente desqualificada. Se olhar bem, parece que não tem emprego para C e C++, mas tem, só que as pessoas nessa área não trocam tanto assim de emprego, e as vagas são preenchidas muito na base do *networking*.

Se olhar eventos e congressos, algumas linguagens aparecem mais que outras. Novamente C e C++ praticamente desaparecem, porque se a pessoa só usa para exercício da faculdade não vai nesses lugares, e se ela é profissional mesmo nisso consegue obter seu conhecimento de outras formas ou tudo em inglês.

Se olhar o SO ou sites semelhantes significa apenas que a documentação é ruim, que as pessoas interessadas naquela tecnologia são mais preguiçosas ou desqualificadas, ou que a tecnologia dá muito problema. Também tem o outro lado. D quase não tem pergunta no SO, mas porque a comunidade decidiu centrar em fórum próprio. Há distorção por vários motivos. Ou você acha que R está sendo tão usada assim quanto parece?

Se olhar buscas indica só que há interesse por aquilo, mesmo que seja só curiosidade. Ou pode ser só falso positivo, fácil de acontecer.

Livros, conferências e artigos indicam isso também.

Blogs e afins indicam mais engajamento da comunidade, não necessariamente uso.

Github olha apenas para o *open source*. Tem projetos que costumam ser muito internos, quem usa não faz alarde, ou você acha que ninguém mais usa COBOL ou Clipper? Você se surpreenderia. Tem linguagem que não tem, ou não tinha tanto espírito de comunidade. Tem linguagem que o povo não é muito adepto da internet. Tem comunidade que bate o bumbo mais forte do que é usado de fato.

Se você anda por certos círculos tendem achar que aquilo é muito mais popular que realmente é, e tende achar que as outras coisas não são tão usadas assim, especialmente essas que são mais discretas.

A realidade é que é muito difícil afirmar o que é mais usado, a margem de erro é altíssima, só dá para ter uma noção olhando muitas fontes. Só não use o TIOBE como referência. VB.NET mais usado que JS e C#? Hilário! Eu poderia citar tantas inconsistências ali, mas o número de combinações é muito grande.

Podemos dizer que JavaScript é a linguagem de programação tradicional ([excetuo Excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99642/101), mas hoje talvez JS já ganhe porque planilhas não são tão usadas assim, embora seja muito mais que eu gostaria) mais usada porque as pessoas adotam web em exagero e é praticamente a única opção para *frontend web* (junto com [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) agora) e é opção para *backend*. [Java, C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/101), Python e PHP são muito usadas pra *backend*, e exceto a última, um pouco para desktop também (sim, ele ainda é importante). Essas são disparadas as mais usadas e pouco importa qual é a mais usada.

C e C++ ainda tem forte utilização, mas o grosso do interesse visível é por causa de faculdade e afins. Swift existe no mapa por causa do iOS, [Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101) vem crescendo. Delphi está em modo sobrevivência, e Ruby perdendo espaço. [Perl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225745/101) quase morreu de fato. [Go](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227429/101) anda crescendo, [Rust](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249783/101) e [D](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105117/101) servem bem a alguns nichos. R me parece que tem um uso mais acadêmico, mas forte. BASIC sobrevive, principalmente com VB.NET. [Lua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) tem seu nicho. Mas ainda tem espaço para [COBOL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19187/101), Fortran, [Clipper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101). Ou ainda podemos falar de algum uso das linguagens funcionais como Haskell, OCAML e F#, Scala, etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Note que sua pergunta tem uma certa tendenciosidade para o Python, portanto eles conseguiram o que queria, vender a ideia que Python é sensacional." Não havia pensando nisso! Muito obrigado mesmo, resposta completa!

Comment: A coisa mais importante sobre o TensorFlow (sempre tido como um exemplo de python) é que, na sua maior parte, o core não está em Python: mas em uma combinação de C++ e CUDA altamente otimizados (linguagem da Nvidia para programação de GPUs). E por sua vez, usando Eigen (uma biblioteca numérica C++ e CUDA de alto desempenho) e cuDNN da NVidia (uma biblioteca DNN muito otimizada para GPUs NVidia, para funções como convoluções). Mas é como o colega acima falou, manada.

Comment: "Java é bem mais usada que Python, C# também, nem se fala em JavaScript, e até PHP ainda é mais usada." Você pode me passar a fonte desses dados? Eu vi reportagens dizendo que Python já tinha ultrapassado a maioria dessas ai

Comment: @ViniciusMacelai cite a fonte, vamos ver se é chute ou se tem alguma relevância e fundamentação. Em lugar algum vemos isso. Embora tenha diminuído ainda se faz muito a piada, que ainda vale um pouco, programador de Python é desempregado, muita gente brincando poucas trabalhando com ela. Como eu disse abaixo, qualquer lugar que diga que qualquer linguagem é mais usada que JS está falando algo muito errado e isso é de uma obviamente absurda. Ainda que u eu ache um erro usarem tanto assim.

Comment: @Maniero esse é ponto, eu não tenho a fonte de pronto, após uma pesquisa rápida, lebmbrei o da IEEE https://spectrum.ieee.org/at-work/innovation/the-2018-top-programming-languages e queria validar a sua fonte. Aqui na minha região a demanda de programadores python aumentou consideravelmente, passando java.

Comment: Você leu esse ranking? Ele sequer é sobre utilização. Por isso que eu digo a pessoa pega qualquer lista, que não tem critério algum definido e considera que aquilo é a utilização da linguagem. Nem esse, nem Tiobe, nem qq outro site diz qual é a mais utilizada. Juntando várias informações e tendo um pouco de bom senso dá para inferir alguma coisa aproximada. Novamente, qualquer fonte que diga que alguma linguagem que é universal, que é usada como frontend, seja menos usada que uma backend (que tem várias tecnologias concorrentes e pulverização, tem até JS), está completamente furada.

Comment: Análise de região, de setor, de "pessoas que eu conheço" não são válidas para dizer o que se usa mais como um todo. Tudo isso é percepção não realizada. Sorte de quem tem a percepção que bate com a realidade, mas isso nem sempre acontece. Por isso que as pessoas ficam louquinhas com Microsserviços, DDD, NoSQL, porque tem muita gente falando no assunto e parece que tá todo mundo usado. Certo não tem 0,1% das pessoas usando porque essas coisas não são para uso geral assim, vira a moda.

Comment: E é o que eu falei, agora todo mundo aprende Python porque todo mundo está aprendendo Python. Quando o certo era as pessoas estudarem computação, engenharia, ciência para tomar melhores decisões e embasadas e assim estarem preparadas para a tecnologia correta, não para a moda do momento. Comentei mais abaixo como deve se buscar essas informações, e como nada será 100% nesse assunto.

Answer (score 3):

1- Para iniciantes, Python é incrivelmente fácil de aprender e usar. Na verdade, é uma das linguagens de programação mais acessível disponível. Parte do motivo é a sintaxe simplificada com ênfase na linguagem natural. Mas também é porque você pode escrever código Python e executá-lo muito mais rápido. Além disso, é poderoso e por ter estas características se tornou uma das linguagens mais utilizadas para se programar redes neurais. Veja o tensorflow do Google por exemplo.

2- Sabendo que ambas as linguagens são "antigas" para o padrão de programação, 1989 para o python e 1995 para Java eu diria que embora o Java faça tudo que o python faz, o java tem uma curva de aprendizado maior que o python e carece muitas vezes da naturalidade da linguagem que python se tornou. Mas Java ainda é uma linguagem essencial para qualquer programador, principalmente se quer programar mobile. No meu caso, acho uma linguagem simplesmente divertida de se programar, bem mais do que java. Mas eu repito, no meu caso.

Comment: Eu não diria que _"Java ainda é uma linguagem essencial"_, hoje existe muitas linguagens e, apesar de ainda ser a mais usada, Java não seria essencial, nem mesmo para um programador mobile, até porque a linguagem oficial é Kotlin, fora que muitos criam aplicações mobile com React Native, Ionic, Flutter, etc.

Comment: Você está correto. É porque java tai a tanto tempo que a gente acaba exagerando. Eu gosto bastante de React Native.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam se kotlin virou "a" linguagem oficial, eu não estou sabendo. Para mim ela e o Java são ambas linguagens oficiais.

Comment: No Java a jre faz o load de arquivos ja compilados, após implementado os arquivos compilados que é o caso do Java são muito mais rápidos do que interpretados que é o caso do Python. Um problema que o pessoal reclamava é que o Java "carregava muita coisa" em memória, mas isso foi resolvido a partir do java 9 com o jigsaw.

Answer (score 3):

Só complementando **uma parte** da resposta do [@Maniero♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero), onde ele faz uma comparação sobre a linguagem *Java* e o *Python*:

> Java é bem mais usada que Python

Existe um site de uma empresa de qualidade de software bacana que contém uma lista com as posições das linguagens mais usadas no mundo. Se trata do [TIOBE](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/). Nele há informações que podem tirar algumas dúvidas suas em relação à maior usabilidade entre as linguagens e sua porcentagem em relação aos demais.

**@editada**

Também podemos conferir outro ranking muito interessante das linguagens de programação mais usadas nos ultimos 5 anos, com um Top 10 baseado em projetos criados e desenvolvidos no [GitHub](https://octoverse.github.com/projects#languages).

Comment: Vale lembrar que nessa atualização de **Janeiro/2019**,  eles mencionam a linguagem _Python_ como a linguagem de programação do ano, possuindo destaque com relação às outras linguagens.

Comment: Obrigado por mencionar o site, vou  dar uma olhada sim!

Comment: De nada cara, eu acho o site muito interessante, inclusive ele é citado em muitos livros de programação na parte de curiosidades.

Comment: E esta estatística não é nada confiável. Todo mundo que é experiente não o considerada como verdade. Olhar o que as pessoas perguntas no Stack Overflow ou colocam no Github dá uma ideia melhor. Mesmo isso dá ideia errada porque isso tem seu lado tendencioso por uma série de fatores que nem sempre entendemos, pode ser coisas que entram mais em open source do que outras, (C# é bem mais usada do que parece, mas tem pouca coisa open, comparado com outras), ou porque a documentação é muito ruim ou dá muito problema ou tem muito programador ruim e gera mais suporte, ou ainda pode ser porque a...

Comment: ...linguagem tem comunidade mais ativa, ou tem mais empregos porque tem mais rotatividade naquela área, ou vende mais livros porque tá na moda, mas não é algo sustentável, ou tem muita pergunta ou artigos porque se usa muito na faculdade, mas não na prática. Por que acha que C é tão usada assim? Ela nem é usada tanto assim de fato (é bastante, mas não tanto quanto parece). Alguém acha que C é mais usada que JS? Qualquer índice que não coloque JS em primeiro tá errado.Enfim, tem muita coisa pra listar tudo.O Tiobe index pode ser usado para ter uma noção, mas não como dado confiável e definitivo

Comment: Concordo totalmente com você, sendo assim, seria difícil encontrar uma estatística sobre esse assunto confiável, quando se trata de linguagens de programação a diversidade é gigante e o que mais importara nesses casos seriam os critérios usados na formulação dos resultados. O TIOBE possui um [link](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/programming-languages-definition/) explicando os critérios usados no seu mecanismo de definições dos índices exibidos nas tabelas.

Comment: Legal vc ter postado o "ranking" do TIOBE. Gosto bastante [desse aqui do Github](https://octoverse.github.com/projects#languages).

Comment: Bacana cara, acho até válido fazer uma edição da resposta para adicionar esse ranking do Github.

Comment: Boa George! também acho válido André, quanto mais fontes melhor!

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann é uma boa referência, mas só para projetos *open source*. Derruba todas linguagens que são usadas mais em projetos internos, o que distorce bastante a utilização real. Por isso que tem que olhar várias fontes e fazer um caldo.

Comment: @Maniero, sim, você tem toda razão eu costumo olhar bastante o da TIOBE também que já está nos comentários e uso também como referência [as tags do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)!! hehe

Comment: Atrasado aqui, mas enfim, [aqui](https://www.tabnews.com.br/kht/4606e326-d3c9-4a68-b97e-231a927ee66f) eu fiz uma análise do TIOBE, que mostra como ele não deve ser levado a sério. Basicamente, ele conta os hits de buscas pelo termo `+"[language] programming"`. A lista de linguagens e sites está [aqui](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/programminglanguages_definition/), e sei lá porque ele considera resultados de busca no Walmart.com (???) e no Etsy.com (site que vende roupas, calçados, artigos para casa/cozinha/etc) - pra mim, só isso já desqualifica o índice como algo sério...