# O que é um mainframe?

Tags: terminologia, servidor, cobol

Estava lendo algumas perguntas antigas, e acabei me deparando com um [tópico sobre COBOL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19187/por-que-cobol-ainda-%C3%A9-a-linguagem-preferida-no-mundo-dos-neg%C3%B3cios/) onde falava sobre mainframes. O que é um mainframe, e qual a diferença entre um mainframe e um servidor [como conhecemos hoje](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_cliente%E2%80%93servidor)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De forma geral sempre foi conhecido como um computador de grande porte, em oposição aos computadores menores.

Eles costumavam (ou até são em alguns raros casos) usados para tarefas bastantes complexas (para os padrões da época) e rodar aplicações críticas e que precisa(va)m estar centralizadas. Em muitos casos era um computador central de uma organização que tinha outros computadores para outras atividades.

Eram feitos para aguentar o tranco e ser mais confiáveis que o resto dos recursos. Costumavam ser bem modulares (até o processamento podia ocorrer em módulos, era como se tivesse vários processadores que eram diferentes do que usamos hoje). Eram máquinas servidoras mesmo, não como é hoje que as pessoas usam hardware comum para servir algo por ser mais barato e criam redundância distribuindo (que muitas vezes é bem mais difícil fazer funcionar direito)

Era muito comum eles serem acessados por terminais burros (só tinha tela e teclado que comunicava só os caracteres que entravam e saiam dele para o computador sem nenhum processamento (zero mesmo, não tinha qualquer coisa nem próxima de um processador, ainda que depois tenha começado ter alguma coisinha e até mesmo começou ser feito por software que emulava o terminal). O nome pode advir disto também, porque os terminais eram conectados ao **quadro principal** de computação, o nome que de certa forma hoje muita gente chama, erroneamente, de CPU (quando falam daquele gabinete que o monitor, teclado, *mouse* e outros periféricos vão ligados.

De fato, hoje você tem na mão ou bolso mais poder computacional que um *mainframe* tinha :)

Em geral ele roda *jobs*, que é parecido com o que muitos chamam de microsserviços hoje :D grande novidade! Ou seja, eram *scripts*.

Era comum eles serem alugados de tão caros que eram e exigiam muita manutenção. Em alguns casos você o acessava por um período de forma remota e pagava pelo uso (conhece algo assim hoje? :) o pessoal acha que estão usando modernidades agora).

Melhor foto que achei pra ilustrar (tem muita por aí que mostram o terminal e unidade de fita magnética que são periféricos e não o *mainframe* em si, ali no fundo tem alguma coisa, parece até um perfurador de fita de papel, tem fita magnética bem ao fundo):

[image: Mainframe]

Eu já usei um da Unisys :) COBOL mesmo.

Em algum aspecto ele é um servidor, mas funciona de uma forma um pouco diferente. Um pouco menos se você já teve contato com *thin clients* que são terminais burros (ainda que muitos funcionem em cima de um inteligente). Também lembra um pouco como se acessa por SSH ou RDP.

Servidor é um termo mais amplo e até ambíguo sem um contexto, então ele servia algo sim, mas não era comum ser por rede como é hoje (até existia casos de algum tipo de rede, mas era mais raro).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Meu primeiro contato sério com Unix foi em terminal burro serial (mas ja era moderno, SCO OpenServer) - Antes disso teve o Mainframe da Gurgel, era serial tb. Lá usavam Paradox, provavelmente era DOS :) - Conheci umas "velharias assim" no Banespa, os HDs pareciam mais como vasos sanitários, pela forma e tamanho, e tinha umas matriciais de 132 colunas. Ainda bem que deu pra assistir essa "revolução" toda.

Comment: Usei o SCO mas em micro que era o Unix da Microsoft, muita gente não sabe disto. Foi quando usei o Fox para banco de dados. Ele conseguia rodar no Unix e o Clipper não. Era uma beleza de performance porque não tinha que trafegar nada pela rede. Em um emprego eu fiz tudo virar terminal (com Harbour) e revolucionei a empresa. Tudo era lento demais, e tudo ficou instantâneo. Demorou 2 horas pra fazer, porque eu não tinha todas informações da infra e precisou recompilar tudo pra 64 bits e testar se tava ok.

Answer (score 3):

A principal característica do mainframe é que ele não tinha microprocessadores, no estilo dos computadores atuais. Os circuitos que constituíam a CPU (central processor unit) eram grandes e modulares, ocupando armários inteiros. Tinham vantagens, como a redundância, a possibilidade de conserto, etc.

A ALU (unidade aritmética e lógica) era um circuito separado da CPU em si, que apenas despachava instruções.

Textos antigos ainda mencionam a ALU como algo separado da CPU, embora todo microprocessador (que a gente chama de CPU) tenha ALU embutido, mesmo os de 8 ou 4 bits.

Hoje em dia se apelida "mainframe" qualquer central de computação centralizada com alta capacidade de processamento, porém os mainframes atuais utilizam microprocessadores semelhantes aos PCs e workstations Unix.

Answer (score -4):

Ratifico a resposta do user196440. Trabalho em um banco como analista de suporte a softwares que rodam sob sistema operacional z/OS versão 2.4, em mainframe IBM z14. Estamos migrando para z15, que é o mais recente hoje. No mainframe, roda a maior parte do processamento online, nas linguagens Assembly, Cobol, PL/I ou C, gravando em banco de dados IBM DB2. Estamos falando de transações bancárias em agências, operações com cartões de crédito e débito, cadastro, investimentos, contabilidade, empréstimos e financiamentos, entre outras. Na plataforma distribuída (Windows e Linux), ficam algumas operações de ponta, como mobile, home e office banking via browser, extratos, que igualmente vão buscar dados atualizados no DB2 (mainframe).
Mainframe é atual e o ramo bancário é só um exemplo. Google, Amazon e outros gigantes com certeza fazem uso dessa infraestrutura para oferecer seus serviços em escala global.

Comment: A pergunta da página é **O que é um mainframe?**. Acho que esse texto não responde em nada a pergunta feita. O texto ratifica o texto de outro usuário que também não focou e não conseguiu responder a pergunta da página, contou sua experiência com mainframes mas em momento algum teve a consideração com o autor da pergunta dada a falta da explicação **do que é um mainframe e qual a diferença de um mainframe para um servidor moderno**

Comment: Compreendo que ninguém tem a mesma forma de absorver conteúdo, mas com certeza todas as respostas publicadas aqui mostram o histórico e a atualidade dos Mainframes e respondem à pergunta original do autor. Resumidamente, Mainframe também pode ser considerado um servidor moderno, apesar do primeiro ter sido criado na década de 60. Hoje somente a IBM produz. Unisys e HP deixaram de produzir há bastante tempo. Seu modelo mais recente chama-se z15 com até 190 processadores, até 40TB de memória interna, até 6TB de memória Flash e fisicamente é um pouco maior que um refrigerador frost free.

Comment: Complementando, ele possui dois notebooks chamados Support Element (SE) em seu interior para o operador emitir os comandos necessários. A grande diferença entre servidores Windows e Linux em comparação com servidor Mainframe é seu uso voltado ao ambiente empresarial, pela sua alta capacidade de processar milhões de operações ao dia e não precisar de reboot (chamado IPL) por mais de um ano, com a limitação de aceitar programas em poucas linguagens de programação compiladas, como Assembler, Cobol, PL/I e C, e as linguagens interpretadas JCL (Job Control Language) e Rexx.

Comment: Edite a resposta a acrescente o conteúdo.

Comment: Lembrando que o [Stack Overflow não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum), nós somos um [site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow) sobre linguagens de programação.

Answer (score -5):

Parte da resposta acima está correta, mas eles,os Mainframes (com M maiúscula), não são passado. Ele impõe respeito e podem processar milhões de transações em segundos e são tão rápidos que um time-stamp pode dar como duplicado se usado como chave, já ocorreu comigo.
Não se usa mais fita magnética, eu vi usar, e nem mais cartões perfurados, e muito menos terminais burros, e, até usam mouse.
A história dele é sua evolução são fantásticos, eles sãouito usados em bancos ou grandes empresas para por exemplo fazer um planejamento de produção de um determinado produto, imagine como vc organizaria a produção de um carro, estoque, linha de produção, estoque de chão de fábrica, entregas, pedidos a fornecedores, etc etc....nos bancos ele vence toda a demanda de transações recebidas que devem ser armazenadas em arquivos temporários (nuvens) os quais sofrem atualizações durante o dia eefetivacoes em.processamento pesados durante a noite.
...
Eles ainda existem, e são gigantes em.processamentos.
Por isto se chamam Alta Plataforma.

Att

Comment: Muita coisa sem nexo numa resposta só (com todo o respeito). Fita magnética [é altamente usada e evolui constantemente](https://gizmodo.com/tape-storage-could-soon-crush-hard-drives-with-400tb-ca-1844246165), repetição de timestamp acontece até em máquina "caseira" já faz MUITOS anos, arquivo temporário não tem nada a ver com nuvem, e mais uma série de outras coisas sem sentido. Você realmente quis dar uma resposta séria, acha que é isso mesmo, ou postou qualquer coisa só pra ver o que iria acontecer? (dúvida legítima, sem zoeira)